# Animation on Videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to know how can we animate the video. I tried animating the Image using the ImageView and it happened very smoothly. But, when I try to animate the VideoView using the animation class, I am able to move the view only but our video is played in the same position.

Can anyone please explain how we can implement it?

Comment: Create a dummy view on top of the videoview. Then animate the both views and you will see animation effect.